# Is there a word for fear of hearing foreign languages?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that specifically describes people who hate it when hearing other people speak foreign languages. It is similar to and subsumed under xenophobia, but manifests mainly in a strong aversion to foreign tongues.

Unlike [xenoglossophobia or foreign language anxiety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_language_anxiety), which describes the anxiety arising from the learning or speaking of a second or foreign language, my targeted word is about the negative reaction to being surrounded by foreign language speakers. I know xenophobia already covers it, but I am looking for something more specific.

Answer (score 4):

Xenolingohassen: Phobia of ***hearing*** foreign language

Described in [this article](https://charterforcompassion.org/xenolingohassen-the-hatred-of-foreign-languages):

> This hatred of other languages [is called] *xenolingohassen* from the Greek *xeno* (foreign/strange) + the Latin *lingua* (language/lingo) + the German *hassen* (hate/hatred). This new term should not be confused with *xenoglossophobia*, which is a clinical anxiety related to hearing foreign languages.

Comment: What's the source of the given definition?

Answer (score -2):

> [xenoglossophobia](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/xenoglossophobia) (uncountable Noun)
>
> A fear of foreign languages.
>
> *Don't let your xenoglossophobia take over: being able to speak Chinese would be a useful skill.*

Comment: Xenoglossophobia was already mentioned by OP, who doesn't believe it fits because it "describes the anxiety arising from the **learning or speaking** of a second or foreign language". If you think this word fits, you need to convince us it's also used for fear of **hearing** foreign languages.

Comment: The heading of the OP's question is about **a word meaning fear of hearing a foreign language**. You want to be convinced with the use of the word **xenoglossophobia** in that sense. You can see the word *xenoglossophobia* in my answer (from Wiktionary) and its explanation ***a fear of foreign languages***. The link provided by the OP gives explanations of ***xenoglossophobia***,which include the word *apprehension* meaning **fear** - fear of not only speaking, writing or reading a foreign language but also **listening** to it.  *Listening* can mean *hearing*, can't it?

Comment: @All down-voters: You may rather ignore my answer and go with the link given by the OP. Then, you decide whether or not the Wikipedia explanation of the word *xenoglossophobia* covers the meaning of *fear of hearing a foreign language*.

Comment: @mahmudkoya The voters have voted and moved on. They will not even be aware of your comment. Only those of us who follow will read your comment and we will make our own choice, regardless.